# How to make a loop on the results of loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a function which returns array of objects.

`const matches = checkMatching(param1, param2, param3);`

Function checkMatching returns array and I want on that array call another function checkMatching. And then if checkMatchingfunction still returns array I want to recall checkMatching on that array. Summarizing I want to create infinite loop until chechMatching won't  returns array;

Basically I'm trying to create array

`let allMatchingWords = []`

Which collects all results from loops.

Currently I have something like this

```
const checkMatching = (board, r, c) => {
  const top = board[r - 1] !== undefined && { row: r - 1, column: c };
  const bottom = board[r + 1] !== undefined && { row: r + 1, column: c };
  const left = board[r][c - 1] !== undefined && { row: r, column: c - 1 };
  const right = board[r][c + 1] !== undefined && { row: r, column: c + 1 };

    const directionsWithMatches = [top, bottom, left, right]
    .filter(dir => dir instanceof Object)
    .filter(({ row, column }) => board[row][column].word === board[r][c].word);

  return directionsWithMatches;


};
const matches = checkMatching(param1, param2, param3);

let allMatchingWords = [];

 matches.map(({ row, column }) => {
    allMatchingWords = [
      ...matches,
      ...allMatchingWords,
      ...checkMatching(param1, param2, param3),
    ];
});
/// removing duplicates
 allMatchingWords = allMatchingWords.filter(
    (v, i, a) => a.findIndex(t => t.key1 === v.key1 && t.key2 === v.key2) === i,
  );
```

But for now there is a shortcut to loop twice.

I tried to create while loop but I'm not sure that it's possible that way.

Comment: do you have some examples and results?

Comment: the data is still missing.